# Get array of dates for hours, days, weeks, months between current date/time and end date/time

Tags: swift, swift3

I want to create a range of Date objects using Swift 3 and was wondering if there is an API somewhere that simplifies what I want to do, for example:

One of the things I want to do is produce a range of Dates for the period of 1 year (January through December), each Date representing the 1st of every month.

I know I can do all this within a loop like so...

```
func monthsInYear() {
   var calendar = Calendar.current
   let date = Date()
   let monthsOfYearRange = calendar.range(of: .month, in: .year, for: date)
   print(monthsOfYearRange as Any)

  if let monthsOfYearRange = monthsOfYearRange {
      let year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)

      for monthOfYear in (monthsOfYearRange.lowerBound..<monthsOfYearRange.upperBound) {
         let components = DateComponents(year: year, month: monthOfYear)
         guard let date = Calendar.current.date(from: components) else { continue }
         print(date.description(with: Locale.current))
      }
   }
}
```

Which produces the following output...

```
Sunday, January 1, 2017 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern Standard Time
Wednesday, February 1, 2017 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern Standard Time
Wednesday, March 1, 2017 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern Standard Time
Saturday, April 1, 2017 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern Daylight Time
Monday, May 1, 2017 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern Daylight Time
Thursday, June 1, 2017 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern Daylight Time
Saturday, July 1, 2017 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern Daylight Time
Tuesday, August 1, 2017 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern Daylight Time
Friday, September 1, 2017 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern Daylight Time
Sunday, October 1, 2017 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern Daylight Time
Wednesday, November 1, 2017 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern Daylight Time
Friday, December 1, 2017 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern Standard Time
```

However, what I'm looking for is an easier more concise way to do this. I want to do the same for **weeks in a given month**, **days within a given week**, **hours within a given day** which I am able to do, but it uses the same loop.

Comment: direction `Calendar` and `DateComponents`.

Comment: @gangelo Your current question says "I have this code and I want to do something else". You want us to help you to write some code but you are not explaining what that code should be doing, therefore we are all marking your question as "unclear". We are here to help but if you don't spend any effort on asking the question, then we won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I went with - stuck with "the loop" :S

```
func monthsInYear() {
   print()
   print("monthsInYear")

   var calendar = Calendar.current
   let date = Date()
   let monthsOfYearRange = calendar.range(of: .month, in: .year, for: date)
   //print(monthsOfYearRange as Any)

  if let monthsOfYearRange = monthsOfYearRange {
      let year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)

      for monthOfYear in (monthsOfYearRange.lowerBound..<monthsOfYearRange.upperBound) {
         let components = DateComponents(year: year, month: monthOfYear)
         guard let date = Calendar.current.date(from: components) else { continue }
         print(date.description(with: Locale.current))
      }
   }
}

func weeksInMonths() {
   print()
   print("weeksInMonths")

   var calendar = Calendar.current
   let date = Date()
   let weekOfYearRange = calendar.range(of: .weekOfYear, in: .month, for: date)
   //print(weekOfYearRange as Any)

   if let weekOfYearRange = weekOfYearRange {
      let year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)

      for weekOfYear in (weekOfYearRange.lowerBound..<weekOfYearRange.upperBound) {
         let components = DateComponents(weekOfYear: weekOfYear, yearForWeekOfYear: year)
         guard let date = Calendar.current.date(from: components) else { continue }
         print(date.description(with: Locale.current))
      }
   }
}

func daysInWeek() {
   print()
   print("daysInWeek")

   var calendar = Calendar.current
   let date = Date()
   let daysInWeekRange = calendar.range(of: .day, in: .weekOfMonth, for: date)
   //print(daysInWeekRange as Any)

   if let daysInWeekRange = daysInWeekRange {
      let year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)
      let month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
      let weekOfMonth = calendar.component(.weekOfMonth, from: date)

      for dayOfWeek in (daysInWeekRange.lowerBound..<daysInWeekRange.upperBound) {
         let components = DateComponents(month: month, day: dayOfWeek, weekOfMonth: weekOfMonth)
         guard let date = Calendar.current.date(from: components) else { continue }
         print(date.description(with: Locale.current))
      }
   }
}

func hoursInDay() {
   print()
   print("hoursInDay")

   var calendar = Calendar.current
   let date = Date()
   let hoursInDayRange = calendar.range(of: .hour, in: .day, for: date)
   //print(hoursInDayRange as Any)

   if let hoursInDayRange = hoursInDayRange {
      let year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)
      let month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
      let weekOfMonth = calendar.component(.weekOfMonth, from: date)
      let day = calendar.component(.day, from: date)

      for hourOfDay in (hoursInDayRange.lowerBound..<hoursInDayRange.upperBound) {
         let components = DateComponents(year: year, month: month, day: day, hour: hourOfDay, weekOfMonth: weekOfMonth)
         guard let date = Calendar.current.date(from: components) else { continue }
         print(date.description(with: Locale.current))
      }
   }
}
```

Which produces the following output when run:

```
monthsInYear
Sunday, January 1, 2017 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern Standard Time
Wednesday, February 1, 2017 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern Standard Time
Wednesday, March 1, 2017 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern Standard Time
Saturday, April 1, 2017 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern Daylight Time
Monday, May 1, 2017 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern Daylight Time
Thursday, June 1, 2017 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern Daylight Time
Saturday, July 1, 2017 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern Daylight Time
Tuesday, August 1, 2017 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern Daylight Time
Friday, September 1, 2017 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern Daylight Time
Sunday, October 1, 2017 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern Daylight Time
Wednesday, November 1, 2017 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern Daylight Time
Friday, December 1, 2017 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern Standard Time

weeksInMonths
Sunday, November 26, 2017 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern Standard Time
Sunday, December 3, 2017 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern Standard Time
Sunday, December 10, 2017 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern Standard Time
Sunday, December 17, 2017 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern Standard Time
Sunday, December 24, 2017 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern Standard Time
Sunday, December 31, 2017 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern Standard Time

daysInWeek
Monday, December 10, 1 at 12:00:00 AM GMT-04:56:02
Tuesday, December 11, 1 at 12:00:00 AM GMT-04:56:02
Wednesday, December 12, 1 at 12:00:00 AM GMT-04:56:02
Thursday, December 13, 1 at 12:00:00 AM GMT-04:56:02
Friday, December 14, 1 at 12:00:00 AM GMT-04:56:02
Saturday, December 15, 1 at 12:00:00 AM GMT-04:56:02
Sunday, December 16, 1 at 12:00:00 AM GMT-04:56:02

hoursInDay
Tuesday, December 12, 2017 at 12:00:00 AM Eastern Standard Time
Tuesday, December 12, 2017 at 1:00:00 AM Eastern Standard Time
Tuesday, December 12, 2017 at 2:00:00 AM Eastern Standard Time
Tuesday, December 12, 2017 at 3:00:00 AM Eastern Standard Time
Tuesday, December 12, 2017 at 4:00:00 AM Eastern Standard Time
Tuesday, December 12, 2017 at 5:00:00 AM Eastern Standard Time
Tuesday, December 12, 2017 at 6:00:00 AM Eastern Standard Time
Tuesday, December 12, 2017 at 7:00:00 AM Eastern Standard Time
Tuesday, December 12, 2017 at 8:00:00 AM Eastern Standard Time
Tuesday, December 12, 2017 at 9:00:00 AM Eastern Standard Time
Tuesday, December 12, 2017 at 10:00:00 AM Eastern Standard Time
Tuesday, December 12, 2017 at 11:00:00 AM Eastern Standard Time
Tuesday, December 12, 2017 at 12:00:00 PM Eastern Standard Time
Tuesday, December 12, 2017 at 1:00:00 PM Eastern Standard Time
Tuesday, December 12, 2017 at 2:00:00 PM Eastern Standard Time
Tuesday, December 12, 2017 at 3:00:00 PM Eastern Standard Time
Tuesday, December 12, 2017 at 4:00:00 PM Eastern Standard Time
Tuesday, December 12, 2017 at 5:00:00 PM Eastern Standard Time
Tuesday, December 12, 2017 at 6:00:00 PM Eastern Standard Time
Tuesday, December 12, 2017 at 7:00:00 PM Eastern Standard Time
Tuesday, December 12, 2017 at 8:00:00 PM Eastern Standard Time
Tuesday, December 12, 2017 at 9:00:00 PM Eastern Standard Time
Tuesday, December 12, 2017 at 10:00:00 PM Eastern Standard Time
Tuesday, December 12, 2017 at 11:00:00 PM Eastern Standard Time
```

Comment: In days in week i gt wrong output. for example in current month and current year 22 November is Sunday but m getting 22 November as Tuesday....See this is the output I get..daysInWeek
My Date: 2020-11-28 07:06:56 +0000
Tuesday, November 22, 1 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+05:53:28
Wednesday, November 23, 1 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+05:53:28
Thursday, November 24, 1 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+05:53:28
Friday, November 25, 1 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+05:53:28
Saturday, November 26, 1 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+05:53:28
Sunday, November 27, 1 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+05:53:28
Monday, November 28, 1 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+05:53:28@gangelo.